# Reactjs, electron assets Folder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I need to dynamic load images from a directory with subdirectories. I added folder images to src and it works as long as I use yarn start to start the application. But the folder is not packaged to the dist build. I tried to add the Folder to package.json

```
     "build": {
             "files":"images"
    }
```

I tried to use public directory like:

```
texturesPath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/data/textures/'
```

I know how to import images but I need the whole directory with 200 sub directories. Do I have to import every single image separately?

Comment: I found the following explanation in the documentation: 
" Note that we normally encourage you to import assets in JavaScript files instead "
I do not agree because what if you have 32566 files in 459 subfolders?
As a workaround they say I should put everything inside public folder and acces folders using process.env.PUBLIC_URL

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder

Did I just find the answer or is there another way to add directories?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> "build": {
>          "files":"images"
> }
> ```

When you set that, your `images` will be packed in to `app.asar`, so you just have to call `path.join(__dirname, '/images/');` to access this folder.

You can extract `app.asar` after install your app and check if `images` directory in there (%localappdata%/programs/[YOUR_APP_NAME]/resources/app.asar).

Comment: 'textureUrl = path.join(__dirname, '/assets/data/textures')'

Ok the files are there and dev (yarn start) works. 

But dist build I get Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @martomstom please extract your app.asar and show me the result https://github.com/electron/asar

Comment: The files are inside app folder. I don't need to add "files":"images" to package.json. The files are there but I get the error.

Comment: It works now! imageURL =  path.join(__dirname, '/assets/data/textures/'); or process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/data/textures/' did not work. I changed it to imageURL = '/assets/data/textures/' and now it works. Are my assets at the wrong place?

Comment: @martomstom As I understand, you didn't pack your app into asar, didn't you?